# Facebook App dynamic description disappeared, "available on the app store"

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've added a Facebook share button to my iOS app using the code here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/#link

I created a dynamic app description, so when posting to a users wall it would return the score, ie: "You scored 17!".

Everything worked fine when testing, (was not using an "iPhone Store ID" value on the Facebook app when testing), however, now that my app is submitted to the app store and has an iPhone Store ID value populated, when sharing to Facebook, the description no longer appears, and I only get the text "Available on the App Store".

I tried reverting iPhone Store ID to blank, as well as to zero, and neither of those steps seem to work. I still only get the text "Available on the App Store" instead of my dynamic description.

Am I missing a simple step here?

Comment: im also having the same problem, and the weird thing is, that when i look for my publish on facebook via my computer, i see the description properly for 1 second and then it disappears, so weird...